# Posterior for Discrete prior from normal sample with known variance

Tags: r, bayesian, posterior

> Given a sample $(1,2,5,2.5,3,7)$, and known $\sigma^2 = 4$ with possible values for prior mean of $(0,0.5,1,1.5)$ all equally likely, find the posterior distribution and the posterior probability that $\mu\leq 1$

So in R I have:

```
> sample = c(1,2,5,2.5,3,7)
> m = c(0,0.5,1,1.5)
> prior = (rep(1/4,4))
> lilklihood = dnorm(mean(sample), mean = m, sd = 2/sqrt(length(sample)))
> posterior = prior*liklihood/sum(prior*liklihood)
> posterior
[1] 0.002021756 0.021735920 0.160607934 0.815634390
```

So my posterior distribution just is this vector correct? The thing I find is that all my values are actually less than 1, so is posterior probability that $\mu\leq 1$ just 1?

Comment: It is not clear what you mean. You mention Dirichlet distribution in the title, but use Gaussians in the code, those two are completely unrelated. It is not clear what are you trying to do.

Comment: @Tim, I think you have misread "Discrete" as "Dirichlet".

Comment: @PeterPang please do not make edits that change the meanings of questions or answers by others. Edits are meant for things like typos, fixing broken links, formatting, etc, not for re-wording the content.

Comment: @Tim, I thought the question was closed because it was not detailed enough and therefore asking for people to edit and add details.

Comment: @PeterPang it was asking OP to edit. Please see https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit

Comment: @Tim so how should I interpret the line "to clarify the meaning of a post without changing it"?

Comment: @PeterPang https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com would be a better place to discuss questions like this, but there is no simple answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The resulting posterior is the posterior probability associated with four possible values for the mean; therefore;
$$
\begin{aligned}
&P(\mu = 0 \vert \textrm{data}) &&= 0.002021756,\\
&P(\mu = 0.5 \vert \textrm{data}) &&= 0.021735920,\\
&P(\mu = 1 \vert \textrm{data}) &&= 0.160607934,\\
&P(\mu = 1.5 \vert \textrm{data}) &&= 0.815634390,\\
\end{aligned}
$$
therefore $P(\mu \leq 1 \vert \textrm{data})$ is given by
$$
\begin{aligned}
P(\mu \leq 1 \vert \textrm{data}) &= P(\mu = 0 \vert \textrm{data}) + P(\mu = 0.5 \vert \textrm{data}) + P(\mu = 1 \vert \textrm{data})\\
&= 0.18436561\\
&\approx 18\%.
\end{aligned}
$$